# Как отправить форму ajax symfony

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony2

У меня есть 2 файла.
Один *html.twig*, второй *php*. В *php* находятся классы с функциями, которые возвращают некоторые массивы данных в *html.twig*. Нужно, чтобы запрос в *php* и обратно, происходил без перезагрузки страницы. То есть допустим есть список товаров, нажал на чекбокс "только новые" и появились только новые без перезагрузки страницы. Ломаю голову уже не первый день, не могли бы вы написать какой-либо пример?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пожалуйста .

```
 function addPosToRoute(posId, routeHeadId)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ path("Nitra_OutletBundle_Pos_To_Route") }}",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        pos: posId,
                        routeHead: routeHeadId,
                        add: $('#' + routeHeadId).is(':checked'),
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if ((data != "Ko"))
                        {
                            $('#count_' + routeHeadId).html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```